# if $\|Tv\|\le\|v\|$ for every $v$ in $V$, then $T$ is normal

Tags: linear-algebra

Question in Linear Algebra:
Well, the title pretty much sums the question up.
I need to prove that if we assume $\|Tv\|\le\|v\|$ for every $v$ in $V$, then $T$ is a normal linear operator. I'm pretty sure it's true even though I am not 100% sure so doubt it abit.
Thanks alot in advance. :)

Comment: Take any non-normal operator, and scale it so its operator norm becomes $\leqslant 1$, and you have a counterexample.

Comment: You may be confusing this with the theorem that if $P$ is a projection which does not expand lengths, then it is an orthogonal (i.e. self-adjoint) projection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $\|Ax\|_2 = \|(x_2,0)^T\|_2 \le \|x\|_2$, hence $\|A\| = 1$. However, it is easy to check that $A$ is not normal ($A^* A - A A^* = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$).

Comment: Thanks. That closed the deal :)